# Undefined when parsing data and getting specific objects

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am using leaflet 1.7.1 and successfully loaded JSON file from the local memory of my machine.
I have an object which looks like this:

```
covid = {"AFG":{"continent":"Asia","location":"Afghanistan","population":38928341.0,"population_density":54.422,"median_age":18.6},
"KOR":{"continent":"Asia","location":"Afghanistan","population":38928341.0,"population_density":54.422,"median_age":18.6},
"KGZ":{"continent":"Asia","location":"Afghanistan","population":38928341.0,"population_density":54.422,"median_age":18.6},
....}
```

**What I want to do is to get countries by their ISO country code(e.g. KOR, KGZ etc).**
Even after converting to object file I cannot get by index like covid[0] but it is not working.
I am new to JS and cannot really handle the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice it's not called JavaScript Array Notation, but rather JavaScript *Object* Notation.

The problem: `covid` is NOT an array. It's an object. Here's a [great read](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp). To fix your problem, you refer to the actual name.

To use it in your project, you could loop through the object and use it like so:

```js
for (let isoCountryName in covid) {
  console.log(`${isoCountryName}`);
}
```

Here's a demo:

```js
var covid = {"AFG":{"continent":"Asia","location":"Afghanistan","population":38928341.0,"population_density":54.422,"median_age":18.6},
"KOR":{"continent":"Asia","location":"Afghanistan","population":38928341.0,"population_density":54.422,"median_age":18.6},
"KGZ":{"continent":"Asia","location":"Afghanistan","population":38928341.0,"population_density":54.422,"median_age":18.6}};
for (let isoCountryName in covid) {
  console.log(`ISO country name: ${isoCountryName}`);
}
```

Comment: Should I use Ajax for this? In my console it is showing nothing

Comment: Heey, thank you. It worked. The problem was I copied the parsed data into new variable which wasn't really object(wrongly copied). I tried with original parsed object and it worked great!

Comment: @noname AJAX for what?

Comment: I run into another problem which is that isoCountryName is not part of an object anymore.  I mean if I have data (eg. isoCountryName.data) in KOR(which is isoCountryName) it return underfined. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: You can get the entire object under the country like this: `covid.AFG` or `covid["AFG"]`.

Comment: Got your point but I have around 200 countries and I am not gonna do that manually :)
How can I do so it worked like covid.isoCountryName while isoCountryName is iso code of all countries in a loop

Comment: @noname read this [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and see the second part of the console.log in the loop.